# Can we use AWS Public DNS as Domian name to enable https on our instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, domain-name

For https it is necessary to have a domain name attached to our ip. As one part of https is to identify that the domain name belongs to the server.

My question is, can we use the AWS Public DNS as our Domain name.AWS Public DNS 
 looks like ec2-**-**-**-***.**-**********-*.compute.amazonaws.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can get a certificate for the amazonaws.com domain.

You could probably create a self-signed certificate if this was just for testing, but if you are creating services for public consumption you will need a domain you control and a valid certificate.